# What is the output of Software Serial .read() function

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, softwareserial, arduino-pro-mini

Hi I am new to arduino development i was using esp8266 using software serial library

> here is the code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial monitor(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  monitor.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  sendDebug("AT");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Hello");
  if(monitor.find("OK"))
  {
   Serial.println(monitor.available());
   Serial.println((int)monitor.read());
   Serial.println((int)monitor.read());
    Serial.println(monitor.available());
   Serial.println("RECEIVED: OK");
    //connectWiFi();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("RECEIVED: None");
  }
}

void loop(){

}


void sendDebug(String cmd){
  monitor.println(cmd);
  Serial.println("Command: "+cmd);
}
```

> Output

```
Command: AT
Hello
2
13
10
0
RECEIVED: OK
```

*All I know is `monitor.available()` return the available bytes that can be read and i can also deduce that these two **bytes** are **O** and **K** but the integer value doesn't corresponds to the **ascii** value of **O** and **K***

can anyone explain what is actually getting printed on the serial monitor what is **13** and **10** ? ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just like https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read :

The `monitor.find("OK");` already consumed the 'O' and the 'K' bytes, (see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Find ) then there were two bytes .available(), a 13=CarriageReturn and a 10=LineFeed, both returned by successive `monitor.read()`s, then zero more bytes in monitor.available().